# Unresolved tokens in C++/CLI

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli, managed-c++

I'm getting linker errors for one of the classes I created.

```
1>Dict.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000006) TwoKeyDict<System::String ^,int>::.ctor
1>Dict.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000007) TwoKeyDict<System::String ^,int>::Get
1>Dict.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000008) TwoKeyDict<System::String ^,int>::Put
1>Dict.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (06000009) TwoKeyDict<int,int>::.ctor
1>Dict.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0600000A) TwoKeyDict<int,int>::Get
1>Dict.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0600000B) TwoKeyDict<int,int>::Put
```

These are in all the places that I try to use the class. Here's the code for the class:

TwoKeyDict.h

```
#pragma once

using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

template<class K, class V>
public ref class TwoKeyDict
{
private:
    Dictionary<K, Dictionary<K, V>^>^ underlyingDict;
public:
    TwoKeyDict();
    V Get(K key1, K key2);
    void Put(K key1, K key2, V value);
};
```

TwoKeyDict.cpp

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "TwoKeyDict.h"

template<class K, class V>
TwoKeyDict<K, V>::TwoKeyDict() {
    underlyingDict = gcnew Dictionary<K, Dictionary<K, V>^>();
}

template<class K, class V>
V TwoKeyDict<K, V>::Get(K key1, K key2) {
    if (underlyingDict->ContainsKey(key1)) {
        if (underlyingDict[key1]->ContainsKey(key2)) {
            return underlyingDict[key1][key2];
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}

template<class K, class V>
void TwoKeyDict<K, V>::Put(K key1, K key2, V value) {
    if (underlyingDict->ContainsKey(key1)) {
        Dictionary<K, V>^>^ secondLayerDict = underlyingDict[key1];
        if (secondLayerDict->ContainsKey(key2)) {
            secondLayerDict[key2] = value;
        } else {
            secondLayerDict->Add(key2, value);
        }
    } else {
        Dictionary<K, V>^>^ secondLayerDict = gcnew Dictionary<K, V>^>();
        secondLayerDict->Add(key2, value);
        underlyingDict->Add(key1, secondLayerDict);
    }
}
```

In the places that I'm trying to use it I'm just doing #include "TwoKeyDict.h"

Comment: Use the *generic* keyword to get template-like generic classes that don't require a .h file.  The C++ version (*template* keyword) doesn't have external linkage, the .NET version (*generic* keyword) does.

Comment: @HansPassant: Generics are only superficially similar to templates.  They're more different than they are alike, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates go in header files, where the implementation can be seen by all users.

Are you sure you wanted to use a template and not a generic?  It doesn't look like you're doing anything that would benefit from specialization.

Comment: I don't think I need a template after all. When I was deciding which one to use, something I was reading seemed to imply that generics didn't work with primitives, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Is that correct?

Comment: @Alex : You're thinking of Java, where primitives get boxed; with .NET, generics work 100% as expected with primitives.